# svelte custom element createEventDispatcher doesn't work

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I'm trying to use createEventDispatcher to catch the child component's event from the parent's component but seems like doesn't work. If I remove the custom element, the dispatcher event works. Am I doing something wrong or svelte custom element doesn't support the dispatcher event?

**child component Inner.svelte**

```
<svelte:options tag="my-inner"/>
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    function sayHello() {
        dispatch('message', {
            text: 'Hello!'
        });
    }
</script>

<button on:click={sayHello}>
    Click to say hello
</button>
```

**parent component App.svelte**

```
<svelte:options tag="my-app" />
<script>
    import {} from './Inner.svelte';

    function handleMessage(event) {
        alert(event.detail.text);
    }
</script>
<my-inner on:message={handleMessage}></my-inner>
```

**My rollup.config.js settings**

```
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            compilerOptions: {
                customElement: true,
                tag: null
            },
        }),
```

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue. At least in 3.32 and before, events are not emitted from svelte component compiled into custom-element.

See https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3119

This thread discuss about various workaround, but it depends of your usecase. The simple one seem to emit yourself an event :

```
import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
import { get_current_component } from 'svelte/internal';

const component = get_current_component();
const svelteDispatch = createEventDispatcher();

const dispatch = (name, detail) => {
  svelteDispatch(name, detail);
  component.dispatchEvent && component.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name, { detail }));
  // or use optional chaining (?.)
  // component?.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name, { detail }));
};
```